# Annotate karyogram with Granges track

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a karyogram/ideogram of human hg19 that contains in addition a track with numeric data, e.g. p-values, as an point plot.

```
    CHROM    POS  fisher_het
 1:    10 134775 0.299587633
 2:    10 135237 1.000000000
 3:    10 135277 0.483198279
 4:    10 135331 0.224587437
 5:    10 135334 0.068035761
 6:    10 135656 0.468998144
 7:    10 135708 0.746611845
 8:    10 135801 0.242257762
 9:    10 135853 0.001234701
10:    10 137186 0.774670848
```

I get this far that i can plot the the p-values in a default ggplot plot, well  with something like this.

```
ggplot(data = my.data.frame,],
       aes(POS, -1 * log(fisher_het))
       ) + 
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.8) + 
    facet_wrap(~ CHROM) + 
    labs(x = "Position on chromosome", y = "-log(raw p-Value)") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 8, size = 0.3)
```

[image: pvalues along chromosome 22]

Now it would be nice to have those p-values plotted on a karyogram/ideogram as a separate track above of each chromosome's karyogram.

[image: human karyogram]

To this end i followed in large part the question of Alexander Skates (https://www.biostars.org/p/152969/).

```
library("ggbio")
library("GenomicRanges")

# load banding data
data(hg19IdeogramCyto, package = "biovizBase")
hg19 <- keepSeqlevels(hg19IdeogramCyto, paste0("chr", c(1:22, "X", "Y")))

# create a test GRanges object
# from the test data given above
test.granges <- GRanges(seqnames = paste0("chr", df.test.data$CHROM),
                        ranges=IRanges(start = df.test.data$POS,
                                       end = df.test.data$POS),
                        strand = "*",
                        fisher_het = df.test.data$fisher_het)

# attach chromosome lengths
data(hg19Ideogram, package = "biovizBase")
seqlengths(test.granges) <- seqlengths(hg19Ideogram)[names(seqlengths(test.granges))]

# plotting trials
# this works - a set of chromosomes with banding
ggplot(hg19) + layout_karyogram(cytoband = TRUE)

# now i want to add my p-values following the pattern of Alexander Skates
# + layout_karyogram(avs.granges, geom = "rect", ylim = c(11, 21), color = "red")
# using geom = "point"
ggplot(hg19) + 
     layout_karyogram(cytoband = TRUE) + 
     layout_karyogram(data = test.granges, 
                      geom = "point", 
                      aes(x=???, y=fisher_het)
                      )
```

I fail to provide valid x and y coordinates in a GRanges object or any other object that get accepted by ggplot/ggbio.

```
# also tried to no avail
ggplot(hg19) + 
    layout_karyogram(cytoband = TRUE) + 
     plotRangesLinkedToData(data = test.granges)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it turned out to be not very difficult if one found the proper URL.

http://www.tengfei.name/ggbio/docs/man/layout_karyogram-method.html points to a line plot above each chromosome's karyogram.

- the x-coordinate from the GRanges object to be used would be `start`
- `ylim` defines the size of the point-subplots
- `size` needs to be reduced a little as default point size would produce a nearly unreadable plot

---

```
ggplot(hg19) + 
     layout_karyogram(cytoband = TRUE) + 
     layout_karyogram(data = test.granges, 
                      geom = "point", 
                      aes(x=start, y=fisher_het),
                      ylim = c(10,50),
                      color = "black",
                      size = 0.4
                      )
```

[image: Ideogram with additional geom_point track]